# ruby DRY return value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, return, dry

This may come across as a silly question, but my rails application is starting to get plagued by this code style:

```
def return_my_object
  @object = get_object
  some_function_work(@object)
  return @object
end
```

Are there general practices or ways to get rid or avoid the `return @object` code? So far I can't think of anything and it seems like cruft code.

Comment: Ruby has implicit returns, meaning that a final line with just `@object` will return the intended value. Additionally, if `some_function_work(@object)` returned `@object`, you could omit the final line of code in your method.

Comment: Haha yea thanks for clarifying! I just wanted to be explicitly clear that I wanted to return `@object` last.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-tap) to simplify that code slightly. Tap yields the object to the block, and returns the object after the block finishes. Thus, it does *not* set `@object` to the value of `some_function_work`, but rather to the result of `get_object`. However, if `some_function_work` alters `@object`, this will obviously be reflected since it is the same instance.

That is:

```
def return_my_object
  @object = get_object.tap { |o| some_function_work(o) }
end
```

The last expression of the method (`@object`) will also be returned.

A minimal example is below, where `{}.tap` yields a new `Hash` instance to the block, which will be returned when the block finishes. Inside the block we alter the Hash, which is reflected in the result that is assigned to `@object`.

```
@object = {}.tap { |hash| hash[:key] = :value }
# { :key => :value }
```